# How to bring up an inactive mdadm RAID after a reboot while adding a drive to a raid-6?

Tags: opensuse, raid, mdadm, webmin

I have been using webmin to manage my RAID array for several years, and I never had any reason to use the `mdadm` commands in the terminal.

However, some days ago, I added a disk to my RAID6 array of six drives and there was no progress in the reshape. I assumed if I reboot the computer, the problem would be solved, but after reboot I am in a bigger problem now.

Although the array is in a clean state after reboot, I cannot start the array on /dev/md3. See the commands and attached webmin screen shots.

[image: Webmin Screenshot for MD RAID]

[image: Webmin Screenshot for /dev/md3]

```
250:~ # cat /etc/os-release
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
# VERSION="20161112"
ID=opensuse
ID_LIKE="suse"
VERSION_ID="20161112"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20161112"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"


250:~ # uname -a
Linux 250 4.8.6-2-default #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 3 13:00:34 UTC 2016 (1d89b44) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


250:~ # rpm -q webmin 
webmin-1.820-1.noarch


250:~ # mdadm -V
mdadm - v3.4 - 28th January 2016


250:~ # cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md127 : active raid6 sdi2[7] sdf2[4] sdc2[2] sdb2[0] sda2[1] sdd2[5] sdg2[6]
      5119360 blocks super 1.0 level 6, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid6 sdc3[2] sdf3[5] sda3[1] sdb3[3] sdd3[4] sdi3[6] sdg3[0]
      153599360 blocks super 1.0 level 6, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md3 : inactive sdi4[7] sdf4[4] sdd4[5] sdb4[0] sdc4[2] sda4[1] sdg4[6]
      3103718444 blocks super 1.0

md0 : active raid6 sdf6[5] sdc6[2] sdb6[4] sda6[1] sdi6[8] sdd6[6] sdg6[7]
      7149870080 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/11 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid6 sdb5[0] sdc5[2] sdd5[5] sda5[1] sdi5[7] sdf5[4] sdg5[6]
      5119993600 blocks super 1.0 level 6, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>


250:~ # mdadm -D /dev/md3
/dev/md3:
        Version : 1.0
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
  Used Dev Size : 443387648 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Raid Devices : 7
  Total Devices : 7
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
          State : active, Not Started 
 Active Devices : 7
Working Devices : 7
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

  Delta Devices : 1, (6->7)

           Name : any:3
           UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
         Events : 139752

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       20        0      active sync   /dev/sdb4
       1       8        4        1      active sync   /dev/sda4
       2       8       36        2      active sync   /dev/sdc4
       4       8       84        3      active sync   /dev/sdf4
       6       8      100        4      active sync   /dev/sdg4
       5       8       52        5      active sync   /dev/sdd4
       7       8      132        6      active sync   /dev/sdi4


250:~ # mdadm -E /dev/sd[abcdfgi]4
/dev/sda4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
           Name : any:3
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 886775528 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
     Array Size : 2216938240 (2114.24 GiB 2270.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 886775296 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Super Offset : 886775792 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=480 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 92f5e8d6:4e55facc:5446de77:ee298eee

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 0
  Delta Devices : 1 (6->7)

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 5c4a0af8 - correct
         Events : 139752

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
           Name : any:3
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7


 Avail Dev Size : 886775528 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
     Array Size : 2216938240 (2114.24 GiB 2270.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 886775296 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Super Offset : 886775792 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=480 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b36bd7a1:ec792d23:51c0e852:e9ba91b5

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 0
  Delta Devices : 1 (6->7)

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 1f79aeed - correct
         Events : 139752

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
           Name : any:3
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 886783720 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
     Array Size : 2216938240 (2114.24 GiB 2270.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 886775296 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Super Offset : 886783984 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=8672 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ab40e58e:724de1e3:e502ccf0:831a93cd

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 0
  Delta Devices : 1 (6->7)

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 8320399c - correct
         Events : 139752

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
           Name : any:3
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 886775528 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
     Array Size : 2216938240 (2114.24 GiB 2270.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 886775296 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Super Offset : 886775792 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=480 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b0f9f68d:0ad6f39a:50043287:10b0570d

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 0
  Delta Devices : 1 (6->7)

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : f6ed233 - correct
         Events : 139752

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdf4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
           Name : any:3
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 886775528 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
     Array Size : 2216938240 (2114.24 GiB 2270.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 886775296 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Super Offset : 886775792 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=480 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c63684ba:59abf1dc:603d3c94:b5efd4b6

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 0
  Delta Devices : 1 (6->7)

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 34815d4d - correct
         Events : 139752

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdg4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
           Name : any:3
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 886775528 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
     Array Size : 2216938240 (2114.24 GiB 2270.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 886775296 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Super Offset : 886775792 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=480 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 9ef6c9e1:5a56c716:4cc8645f:bd92060b

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 0
  Delta Devices : 1 (6->7)

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : b4f6f61a - correct
         Events : 139752

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdi4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec
           Name : any:3
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 12 07:16:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 886775528 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
     Array Size : 2216938240 (2114.24 GiB 2270.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 886775296 (422.85 GiB 454.03 GB)
   Super Offset : 886775792 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=480 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a6046dca:1edf6818:5fe92892:2e3a966f

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 0
  Delta Devices : 1 (6->7)

    Update Time : Thu Nov 17 14:17:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 368f556c - correct
         Events : 139752

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)


250:~ # mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=ad2e4877:bb799c91:49e20b58:c0866104 name=430:0
ARRAY /dev/md/swap  metadata=1.0 UUID=a8f1a9d5:bd89d7db:0764ba4d:5a515066 name=any:swap
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.0 UUID=0d675c76:d91e6dd2:b8b89871:5af91fed name=any:2
ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.0 UUID=51cc1190:dc4821a5:c1161e00:b73e02ec name=any:3
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.0 UUID=8cedcb83:66499024:f9d66cca:7e7b367b name=any:0
```

Comment: `md127` is just a name  of an array and it is ok. I have run `mdadm --examine --scan`. This is the out put:

Comment: What's in `dmesg` when you assemble it?

Comment: The array cannot be assembled when it is stopped, it is only a reboot that assembles the array. The `dmesg` after a reboot is `[   39.576104] md/raid:md3: reshape_position too early for auto-recovery - aborting.`
`[   39.576110] md: pers->run() failed ...`

Comment: Problem solve by recreating the superblock

Comment: using `mdadm --create /dev/md3 -l6 -n6 -c128 --layout=ls  --metadata=1.0 --assume-clean /dev/sdb4 /dev/sda4 /dev/sdc4 /dev/sdf4 /dev/sdg4 /dev/sdd4` . The sequence of the drives is obtained from the output of ` mdadm -D /dev/md3`.

Comment: For future reference, `mdadm --create`  should only be used as a last-ditch, desperation measure to recover a failed array.  If you don't get the parameters exactly right, you'll destroy the array and lose all data on it.

Answer (score 10):

If `mdadm` cannot find all the parts of an array when assembling it, it won't automatically activate it for use.  You can manually activate it with the command `mdadm --run /dev/md3`.  It may start up in read-only mode, in which case you can put it in read-write mode with `mdadm --readwrite /dev/md3`.

This is a safe operation: if there aren't enough pieces of the array available to have a complete set of data (eg. three drives missing from a RAID6, or a matched pair missing from a RAID10), `mdadm` will do nothing.

Comment: These two commands correctly got my array back online after a power loss during a RAID5->6 reshape with an extra drive added.